# Problem regarding running timer in javascript

Tags: javascript, timer

i have written following code to run a timer when a button is clicked and to stop it when another one is clicked. However it works first time when the code loads and also when i click stop timer but when i click start time after that the timer starts running and does not stop on clicking  stop time button again. Here is the code:

```js
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer ,1000);

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}

function settime(){
    var myVar = setInterval(myTimer ,1000);
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>
        <button onclick="clearInterval(myVar)">Stop time</button>
        <button onclick="settime()">Start time</button>
        <p id="demo"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I delete the comment, I did not see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var myVar` redeclares `myVar` within `setTime`, causing it to shadow the outer declaration of `myVar` which `clearInterval` is using.

The solution is to omit the `var` keyword in `setTime`.

You may also want to stop the timer before starting it. Check for correctness by pressing the `Start` button twice before seeing if the `Stop` button works.

Comment: Thanks traktor53, it is working fine now. I am also trying to use the same button for starting and stoping time. i.e. initially the time is running when the window loads and the button text is stop time, when it is clicked the button text changes to start time and the time stops. then again when the same button is clicked its text changes to stop time and the timer starts. should i use innerHTML property of the button for this

Comment: The `innerHTML` property is fine for setting the content of buttons. Refer to [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) on MDN for what content a button can be given.